# Neo4j 3.0.1 and SDN 4.1.1.RELEASE path finding

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have two Decision node - parent and child.

I have implemented following method that returns path between these nodes.

```
@Query("MATCH path=(d:Decision)<-[:CONTAINS*]-(ancestorD:Decision) WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} AND id(ancestorD) = {ancestorDecisionId} RETURN path LIMIT {limit}")
List<Path> findPathsFromDecisionToAncestorDecision(@Param("decisionId") Long decisionId, @Param("ancestorDecisionId") Long ancestorDecisionId, @Param("limit") Integer limit);
```

In `SDN 3.4.4.RELEASE` and `Neo4j 2.3.3` for direct parent and child it reutrns  `1 path`.

Right now in `Neo4j 3.0.1` and `SDN 4.1.1.RELEASE` it returns  `0 path`.

Is it okay or this query should be rewrited ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concept of a `Path` in SDN 4, just hydrated nodes that reference other nodes via relationships.

Your options here are to return nodes and relationships and traverse the object graph (see http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/04/06/mapping-query-entities-sdn.html for examples), or, if you want a strict path, use the underlying GraphDatabaseService (available if you use the embedded driver) and deal with raw nodes and relationships.